# How to order a class list by a property within the classes

Tags: c#, list, sorting, properties

I want to be able to sort the following `List<Player>` by the integer within the `Player` class labelled `rating`. I want the highest `rating` to be the first index within my List of classes, a lot of the integers will be duplicates!

Initiation of the lists.

```
    public List<PriceCheckerParameters> _PriceCheckerList;
    public List<PriceCheckPlayerList> _PlayerList;
    private List<Player> _Players;
```

This is the class that I am storing a List of.

```
public class Player
{

    public enum RatingRank
    {
        Bronze,
        Silver,
        Gold,
    } 
    public int id { get; set; }

    public int nationId { get; set; }

    public int rating { get; set; }

    public RatingRank ratingLevel { get; set; }

    public string firstName { get; set; }

    public string lastName { get; set; }
}
```

This is the function where I am sorting the list and assigning it to another list of another irrelevant class.

```
    public async Task SetPlayerList()
    {
        //returns list of players and stores it to be sorted 
        _Players = await _ItemHandler.GetPlayerList();
        _PlayerList = new List<PriceCheckPlayerList>();

         //This is as much as I am able to get with my knowledge (I'm lacking)
        _Players = _Players.OrderBy()

        foreach (Player eap in _Players)
        {
            _PlayerList.Add(new PriceCheckPlayerList()
            {
                _Player = eap,
                SetYet = false,
                LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow, 
            });
        }
    }
```

I've tried reading looking for other answers but I am unable to wrap my head around the OrderBy or Sort functions.

EDIT: I see your answers but could someone please explain how exactly it works?

Comment: You need to specify sort key: `_players.OrderBy(p=>p.rating)` and you need to do sort after adding players in the list not before.

Comment: Did you try `_Players.OrderByDescending(p=>p.rating)` ?

Comment: @Harsh How exactly does this function work? I'd like to understand it. And that is a different list for a different class which will still have the order I sorted the _Players because _PlayersList is reset each time this function is called meaning the highest rank will still be placed first within the new list of the class within the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by all the previous answers, you can use the extension methods available to you on the List class. They are correct and will result in writing less code, and my preferred way as well, but since no one has mentioned or showed you how to do this in LINQ, I will place it here.

```
List<Player> _PlayerList = new List<Player>()
{
    new Player() { firstName = "TestName1", lastName = "TestSurname1", rating = 1 },
    new Player() { firstName = "TestName2", lastName = "TestSurname2", rating = 2 },
    new Player() { firstName = "TestName3", lastName = "TestSurname3", rating = 3 },
    new Player() { firstName = "TestName4", lastName = "TestSurname4", rating = 4 }
};

var sortedPlayers = from p in _PlayerList
                    orderby p.rating descending
                    select p;

foreach (var player in sortedPlayers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(player.firstName);
}
```

Here, I first initialized your list with some dummy data. As you can see, I then use LINQ to query your List of Players, and order the results in descending order.

This is the results produced.
[image]

If you would like to switch the results around in your list, simply change the 'descending' keyword in the LINQ query to 'ascending', different type of sorting. Here is an example of the opposite results.

```
var sortedPlayers = from p in _PlayerList
                    orderby p.rating ascending
                    select p;
```

This will be the results.

[image]

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a good place to get you started with LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Use `OrderBy` Linq extension, this keeps highest ranking at the bottom .

```
_Players = _Players.OrderBy(p=>p.rating).ToList();
```

Comment: I would like the highest ranking to be the lowest index within the list, is this how it is done?

Comment: @Aidan updated answer to keep highest ranking at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
_Players = _Players.OrderByDescending(player => player.rating).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers before me are correct. I prefer this way because it uses one of the List constructors instead of calling .ToList():

```
//Ascending for first item in list to have the smallest rating value
List<Player> newList = new List<Player>(originalList.OrderByAscending(each => each.rating));
```